# Creating a Layout with a Photo Gallery Authenticator Flexbox

Tags: html, css, layout, photo, image-gallery

I am new to the world of programming, I would like to ask for help in writing html/css code to create a centred layout like the ones in the attached picture. Using Flexbox. What is the easiest method for you?

[image]

Writing the html/css code came out like this for me but I don't like it at all, the images are not centred in the viewport[image]

Comment: please attach your code so we can see it and help you to center your grid

Answer (score 0):

**I have just created a codepen example for you to understand flex better!**

> And I also suggest you use the result on the sides so you can change
> the height-length properties and understand better.

https://codepen.io/Osasingman/pen/JjZdmOP?editors=1100

To sum up you have to give your items   `display: flex;` property to use any flex feature. Then you have to add the `flex-wrap: wrap;` property to distribute all the items to lines.`flex-grow: 1;` is also needed because all the space is going to be distributed equally to all children

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your reply! I saw code pen, but what if I wanted to position the photos centrally as in the photo I attached? The one of the mountain, how should I do it? Also taking into account that I have a header and a footer

Comment: Check the codepen again i changed it a little bit.